# Move sprite with mouse click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I followed a utube tutorial on how to move a sprite by dragging, but I cannot get it to work.

I am new to unity so sorry if this is a bit simple

this is the script attached to my main camera, I have attached a capsule colllider to my sprite

thank you for your help in advanced

The next step is to add touch input

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class DragMove : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject gameObjectToDrag; // refer to Go that being dragged

    public Vector3 Gocenter; // gameobject centre
    public Vector3 touchPosition; // touch or click position
    public Vector3 offSet; // vector between touchpoint/mouse click to the      object centre
    public Vector3 newGOCenter; // new center of object

    RaycastHit hit; // store hit object information

    public bool draggingmode = false; //   



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

    //********************************
    // **Click to Drag****************
    //********************************

    // first frame when user click left button

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        // convert mouse position to ray
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        // if ray hit a collider (not 2dcollider)
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            gameObjectToDrag = hit.collider.gameObject;
            Gocenter = gameObjectToDrag.transform.position;
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint
(Input.mousePosition);
            offSet = touchPosition - Gocenter;
            draggingmode = true;
        }
    }

    // every frame when user hold left mouse
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (draggingmode)
        {
            touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint
(Input.mousePosition);
            newGOCenter = touchPosition - offSet;
            gameObjectToDrag.transform.position = new Vector3(newGOCenter.x, 
newGOCenter.y, newGOCenter.z);
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        draggingmode = false;
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: I click the spite but does not move

Comment: Are you sure this is a sprite? Please post  "Inspector" tab screenshot of that object

Answer (score 0):

GetMouseButtonDown only returns true the first frame. [GetMouseButton](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html) is used to detect when the mouse button is held down.

```
// every frame when user hold left mouse
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
```

should instead read

```
// every frame when user hold left mouse
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
```